# How to use Collectors.groupingBy in java stream without POJO class methods

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am reading a single csv file (size is approximately 700 MB having 103415834 rows) and trying to retrieve all rows having some specific values.
I am able to retrieve the row if it is having only 1 entries but not if it is having more than 1 entries.
Below is my code which work fine for 1 entries.

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(IN_FILE_PATH))) {

        int nameIndex = columns.indexOf("Rate");

        Stream<String> stream1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(IN_FILE_PATH));

        List<List<String>> values = stream1
                .skip(1)
                .map((line) -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
                .filter(list -> list.get(nameIndex).equals("25"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(values.size());
        values.forEach((l) -> System.out.println(l));

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And a sample row for the csv file trying to parse is below:

```
MD,URN,PremiseType,Rate,OHP 09022,null,Residential,14,null 38329,1428275,Residential,14,null 38742,563459,Single,21,111
```

Comment: please show what the entry is and what structure of your csv file

Comment: @Ruslan below is the csv structure                                                                                        MD,URN,PremiseType,Rate,OHP
09022,null,Residential,14,null
38329,1428275,Residential,14,null
38742,563459,Single,21,111

Comment: That code works fine when I run it with your test data, although I filtered on "14".

Comment: @Arvind what is your expected result?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  it will work fine with few hundred of record but when I am running with milltion of records I am getting error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.   So I am trying to use grouping while collecting the data

Comment: @Ruslan I am trying with Rate. However while reading million of records it is failing with all the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is grouping by `Rate` (arr[3]) but you can group by any field you want:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = Files.lines(Paths.get(IN_FILE_PATH))
            .skip(1)
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .collect(groupingBy(arr -> arr[3], 
                     mapping(strings -> String.join(" ", strings), toList())));
```

Key from result `map` is a field you group by(in this case Rate), value(`List<String>`) is a list of rows with the same Rate.

Hope this helped

Comment: thanks for your support. However I am facing syntax error on the last line near String(" ", strings).                                                                                                                            Message as "Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation"

Comment: @Arvind you mean join(" ", strings) ?

Comment: Yes Ruslan. I tried by passing ) in Files.lines(Paths.get(IN_FILE_PATH)) as it was missing.  Then it is showing error as toList method as undefined.

Comment: @Arvind Use `Collectors.toList()`,`Collectors.mapping` and `Collectors.groupingBy`

Comment: @Arvind just to be concise it's assuming you have static import `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` . Or you can fix that as nullpointer suggests